# Spring data JPA - Service always null

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to save User data on database through Spring data JPA.Unfortunately when in my controller class I call RegistrazioneService it comes null.

registrazioneController.java : it's a normal JSF controller ...

```
@ManagedBean(name="registrazioneController")
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrazioneController {

private String username = "";
private String password = "";
private String repassword = "";
private String email;


@ManagedProperty(value = "#{registrazioneService}")
private RegistrazioneService registrazioneService;

public void registraUser() {

    System.out.println("inizio registrazione utente...");

    // si salva nel db il nuovo utente
    User utente = new User();
    utente.setUsername(username);
    utente.setPassword(password);
    utente.setEmail(email);
    utente.setDataCreazione(new Date());

    // di default si assegna all'utente il ruolo ROLE_USER
    utente.setRole(Role.ROLE_USER);

    registrazioneService.registraUtente(utente);
}
```

RegistrazioneService :

```
@Service
public class RegistrazioneService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRespository;

@Transactional
public void registraUtente(User user) {
    System.out.println(("sono in registraUtente()"));
    userRespository.save(user);

}
}
```

and that's UserRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

 }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: add a `setRegistrazioneService` to your controller.

Comment: Can you double check the `@Service` annotation you imported? Is it from `org.jvnet.hk2.annotations` or `org.springframework.stereotype` package?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to put @Autowired instead of @ManagedProperty(value = "#{registrazioneService}") ?

Comment: yes it's null anyway

Comment: Therefore put a constructor so that spring will be able to inject the bean.

public RegistrazioneController (RegistrazioneService registrazioneService){
   this.registrazioneService = registrazioneService;
}

Comment: nothing ... it's null anyway :(

Comment: reason it's null because spring didn't inject the bean into that class

Comment: @mjayson, a question should be posted as a comment to the question, not as an answer, since it implies that more clarification is required from the poster.